# ValueConverter only firing once

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a WPF value converter to convert items of an items control which is firing when the xaml view is loaded.

My issue is that the value converter appears not to be firing when the itemssource collection raises a notify property changed event.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StackupViewModel.Layers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LayerToRectangle}">
                        <Binding />
                        <Binding ElementName="rgv"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ContentPresenter.Content>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my converter

```
public object Convert(
        object[] values,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var layer = values.First() as Layer;
        var radGridView = values[1] as RadGridView;
        var column = radGridView.Columns["Lamination"];
        var row = radGridView.Items[0];
        var cellToEdit = new GridViewCellInfo(row, column, radGridView);
        radGridView.CurrentCellInfo = cellToEdit;
        radGridView.Focus();

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

        if (radGridView.CurrentCell != null)
        {
            Point p = radGridView.CurrentCell.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), radGridView);
            rectangle.Height = radGridView.RowHeight - 10;
            rectangle.Width = column.ActualWidth;
            rectangle.Fill = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(layer.ColorHex);
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, p.Y + layer.LayerNumber);
            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, p.X);
        }





        return rectangle;
    }
```

I added a button to the xaml to fire the notifypropertychanged on the Layers observable collection as so:

```
<Button Name="btnDraw" Command="{Binding StackupViewModel.ScrollCommand}" />

private void ScrollCommandHandler(object offset)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Layers);

}
```

Can anyone advise me why the converter isn't getting fired when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The context of your first binding is just an individual `Layer` object not the `Layers` parent collection so the MultiBinding won't register any `PropertyChanged` when you call your `ScrollCommandHandler` method.

Comment: I thought because the itemscontrol was bound to the Layers observable collection that raising propertychanged on that would cause the itemscontrol to refresh its binding, thus reapplying the coverter to the collection again? Would you be able to advise on how to refire the converter when the button is clicked?

Comment: Feels more like a hack to me but you could add another binding that 'listens' to the actual `Layers` collection, for example: `<Binding ElementName="MyItemsControl" Path="ItemsSource"/>`.